# CSS Z-Index: ¿Puede haber problemas a la larga por un límite?

Tags: jquery, css

Buenas, soy nuevo pero he leído mucho por aquí y me han ayudado un montón. Explico mi situación, estoy con una página web que posee como ventanas (emula un escritorio estilo retro Apple Lisa OS), y hay varias; cuando se hace clic en una de ellas, ésta viene a primer plano con z-index de CSS. Yo uso la siguiente función en JQuery para obtener el z-index más alto así:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.maxZIndex = function(_class)
    {
        var maxZIndex = 0;

        $(_class).each(function(index)
        {
            var tmpIdx = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
            if(tmpIdx > maxZIndex) { maxZIndex = tmpIdx; }
        });

        return maxZIndex;
    }
});
```

Tras obtenerlo, simplemente el contenedor correspondiente (en este caso `<section>`) aplica el z-index máximo obtenido sumando un 1. Mi pregunta es si puede llegar un momento en que se obtenga un valor tan alto como para desbordarse; en ese caso: ¿cómo podría resetear el z-index a un valor inicial cuando un elemento llegue a un tope (por ejemplo, que llegue a 2000)?
Gracias :D

Comment: Como comentario la mayoría de los navegadores tienen un  valor máximo para z-index de 2.147.483.647. El que menor soporta es Safari con 16.777.271 como valor máximo, Existe la posibilidad de alcanzar esos valores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la [definición de `z-index`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) en CSS, se indica que su valor será un entero, pero no se especifica ningún límite en particular. Ese límite vendrá dado por el navegador y/o el sistema operativo que se esté utilizando.

La mayoría de los navegadores definen sus enteros como un número con signo de 32-bits, lo cual te dejará un rango de valores entre −2.147.483.648 y +2.147.483.647, por lo que tendrías que cambiar ventanas de plano más de 2 mil millones de veces antes de ver un posible error... algo que me parece que no será el caso, pero nunca se sabe.

Si te preocupa que eso no sea suficiente, podrías optar por alguna estrategia del tipo:

- Si el valor del `z-index` llega a X, entonces restar X - número de ventanas al `z-index` de cada ventana; o
- Si se selecciona una ventana, en lugar de cambiar su `z-index` moverla al final del contenedor de ventanas (lo cual la convertirá en la ventana principal, porque a igual valor de `z-index`, el que aparezca último se pone sobre los demás). De este modo ni siquiera necesitarías definir valor para `z-index`; o
- Si se selecciona una ventana, darle una clase (que tendrán un `z-index` mayor al de las ventanas) y quitar esa clase cuando otra ventana sea seleccionada. De este modo sólo necesitarías dos valores para `z-index`: ventana activa y ventana normal (no-activa).

Comment: Muchas gracias. Usaré la primera estrategia ya que la segunda no encaja con la idea de la web; y aunque tenga un valor elevado creo que hay que las cosas hay que hacerlas bien. Me has ayudado. :D